# Create a search form

Tags: php

I have a problem with creating search form. How to create search form with php. When i try to load my main page `index.php` its directly to `localhost/404.php`.
Here is my code example:

```
<?php
  include 'includes/config.php';
  if(isset($_GET['search'])) {
    $search = $_GET['search'];
    search($search);
    } else {
      header('Location: 404.php');
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Мөрөөдлийн аяллыг Ориг Трэйвэлээс">
        <meta name="keywords" content="origtravel,Origtravel,Origtravel Жуулчлал,zuuchlal,juuchlal,travel site, Itgelt hamba, baigali nuuriin ayalal, aylal, turk, turk aylal, istanbul, antalya, pamukkale, vietnam aylal, cambodia aylal, vietnam, cambodia, laos, итгэл хамба, итгэлт хамба, улаан үүд, улан уде аялал, улаан үүд аялал, аватар аялал, манжуур аялал, вьетнам аялал, ханой, дубай аялал, камбож аялал, лаос аялал, турк, түрк, турк аялал, түрк аялал, анталия, анталъя, анталяа, памуккале, памуккалэ, истанбул, стамбул, истамбул, хямд аялал, hainan ayalal, hainan, hainan aylal, хайнань, хайнань аялал, хайнан, хайнан аялал, сочи, москва аялал, санктпетербург аялал, санктпетербург, сояи аялал,">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/vendor-css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/vendor-css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/vendor-css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/vendor-css/swiper.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/app.css">
    <title><?php echo (isset($title)) ? $title:'Мөрөөдлийн аяллыг Ориг Трэйвэлээс'; ?></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php include '_menu.php'?>
```

But its not working correctly how should i fix this. Here is my `menu.php`:

```
<li class="nav-item">
      <form action="" method="GET">
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Хайлт хийх" aria-label="search_input">
        <button type="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
      </form>
    </li>
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: What's not working?

Comment: at the moment the question is to unclear / broad to answer - please add an explanation of desired results / what's going wrong

Comment: i've edited my question. When i try to load my page its directly go `localhost/404.php`.

Comment: `index.php` needs to be be `index.php?search=something` as it currently is written

Comment: Well of course it does, because $_GET['search'] won’t be set until you submit the form.

Comment: You're always looking for a parameter called search in your address bar, on initial load it's probably not there.

Comment: It would be better to store your PHP in a different script if you're going to do it like that.

Comment: Then correct placement of `code` ?

Comment: You could always POST it across rather than GET, and add a hidden input, which if set, you then do the logic, if not set, it renders the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

From my comment above:

```
<li class="nav-item">
      <form action="" method="POST">
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" />
        <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Хайлт хийх" aria-label="search_input"/ >
        <button type="submit">
          <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
        </button>
      </form>
    </li>
```

Rest of code:

```
<?php
  include 'includes/config.php';
if(array_key_exists('submitted', $_POST)) {
  if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    search($search);
    } else {
      header('Location: 404.php');
    }
}
?>
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="Мөрөөдлийн аяллыг Ориг Трэйвэлээс">
        <meta name="keywords" content="origtravel,Origtravel,Origtravel Жуулчлал,zuuchlal,juuchlal,travel site, Itgelt hamba, baigali nuuriin ayalal, aylal, turk, turk aylal, istanbul, antalya, pamukkale, vietnam aylal, cambodia aylal, vietnam, cambodia, laos, итгэл хамба, итгэлт хамба, улаан үүд, улан уде аялал, улаан үүд аялал, аватар аялал, манжуур аялал, вьетнам аялал, ханой, дубай аялал, камбож аялал, лаос аялал, турк, түрк, турк аялал, түрк аялал, анталия, анталъя, анталяа, памуккале, памуккалэ, истанбул, стамбул, истамбул, хямд аялал, hainan ayalal, hainan, hainan aylal, хайнань, хайнань аялал, хайнан, хайнан аялал, сочи, москва аялал, санктпетербург аялал, санктпетербург, сояи аялал,">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/vendor-css/reset.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/vendor-css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/vendor-css/all.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/vendor-css/swiper.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../assets/css/app.css">
    <title><?php echo (isset($title)) ? $title:'Мөрөөдлийн аяллыг Ориг Трэйвэлээс'; ?></title>
  </head>
  <body>
  <?php include '_menu.php'?>
```